# Can we add a invisible image watermark to another image in Android? If yes then how?

Tags: android, image, image-processing, watermark

I need the code to add invisible watermark to another image in Android

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How might I add a watermark effect to an image in Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10679445/how-might-i-add-a-watermark-effect-to-an-image-in-android)

Comment: I don't think it's the same thing, he's looking for an invisible watermark. He doesn't want a faint logo watermark, he wants a way to track the image I guess.

Comment: StackOverflow isn't a rent-a-coder service. What have you tried so far? We can advise where you're going wrong but we can't do the entire thing for you without any sign of effort on your part.

Answer (score 0):

As the comments mentioned, Stackoverflow isn't a free coding service. I will provide you with a high level design advice from which you can implement your own code.

Invisible watermark could just be metadata. The point is to make your particular photo unique and identifiable, right? I would recommend you looking into image metadata manipulation for a simple solution.

That being said, if you are looking for some high tech stealthy watermarking, then you might be looking for pixel manipulation. You can change a few of the pixel colors so if it's compared with the original image with the naked eye, it looks identical but if compared with their base64 encoding you can see a difference. Simply create your own pattern as some sort of signature to attach to images to identify them.

Both method allows you to determine if an image is yours due to the "watermark" you leave on it.

Comment: Yes I want an invisible watermark. I did not mean to imply that it was a rent a code service. I simply meant to ask that if you could point me in the right direction. I am new at this so I need all the help I can get

Comment: Yeah, you can either edit the metadata of picture or manipulate bits / pixels of the picture as I mentioned. That should serve to make your photos "unique" and "identifiable"

Comment: Actually I want to hide an image in a carrier image for security purposes. Like if I want to send a secret image the app will hide it for me in a carrier image and at the destination the person can extract the message. I hope I am explaining it okay.