# How to draw a text at the corner of a bitmap android

Tags: android, android-canvas, android-bitmap

I have a bitmap and I am trying to draw a text over the bitmap at the top right corner. But at the first place I am not able to draw any text over it. I am converting a layout to bitmap and then trying to draw text over it. But its not working out. Here is my code:

```
private Bitmap viewToBitmap(LinearLayout layout) {
        Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(layout.getWidth(), layout.getHeight(), Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
        Canvas canvas = new Canvas(bitmap);
        layout.draw(canvas);
        canvas=new Canvas(bitmap);
        Paint paint = new Paint();
        paint.setColor(Color.BLACK);
        paint.setAntiAlias(true);
        paint.setTextSize(14.f);
        paint.setTextAlign(Paint.Align.CENTER);
        canvas.drawText("Hello Android!", 0, 0, paint);
        return bitmap;
    }
```

Comment: Are you fetching your bitmap dynamically or you have it static in your layout ?

Comment: static layout. @VivekMishra

Comment: `0, 0` will have your text at top left corner

Comment: Then use a framelayout

Comment: I am not able to draw any text. @AbdulKawee

Comment: check this out https://stackoverflow.com/a/10684236/5148289

Comment: Should I wrap FrameLayout over the LinearLayout? @VivekMishra

Comment: Remove linearlayout and use framelayout

Comment: How can I put it at the corner of the bitmap ? @MikeM.

Comment: @V-rundPuro-hit I tried that. But text is not visible in the bitmap.

Comment: Actually there is a specific reason I am using LinearLayout @VivekMishra

Comment: Using linear layout you can't overlap things. In linear layout items will be either aligned horizontally or vertically. You have to use either relative layout or frame layout.

Comment: I am converting the linearlayout in a bitmap and then I am trying to draw on that bitmap. @VivekMishra

Comment: I don't understand the reason for converting it to bitmap for static layout. You can design your view with relative layout too. Why do you want to use Linear Layout only ?

Comment: I want to add a watermark while sharing the layout as image to other apps. @VivekMishra

Comment: Then use relative layout.Keep your watermark view hidden when you don't want it and when sharing make it visible again

Comment: so there is image in that layout or just empty layout?

Comment: when user click on the share button..i am making the hidden layout visible..but that is also visible to the user for some duration of time on the screen.

Comment: There are two images in the layout. So I am converting the layout into bitmap and trying to draw a watermark over it.

Comment: my point is if you are converting layout into bitmap. why don't add that text as a textview inside that layout and covert it with textview. there will be no need for paint or canvas.

Comment: actually the user will share the image..so while sharing i need to draw that watermark on the image..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please pay much attention to the text position & alignment.

```
private Bitmap viewToBitmap(View view)
{
    Bitmap result = Bitmap.createBitmap(view.getWidth(), view.getHeight(), Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
    Canvas canvas = new Canvas(result);
    view.draw(canvas);

    Paint paint = new Paint();
    paint.setColor(Color.BLACK);
    paint.setAntiAlias(true);
    paint.setTextSize(14);
    paint.setTextAlign(Paint.Align.RIGHT);
    canvas.drawText("Hello Android!", view.getWidth(), 14, paint); // draw watermark at top right corner
    return result;
}
```

Comment: one upvote for paint.setTextAlign(Paint.Align.RIGHT); i miss that in my answer